# OWL API Reasoner.getTableau throws NullPointer

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I am trying to do some simple stuff with the owl api. For this, I created an ontology, made up some classes and SubClassOf Axioms. After this, I try to use the Reasoner Hermit to do stuff with it. But when i call one of hermits methods, I get a Null Pointer Exception. This is my actual example:

```
public class Main {
    static OWLOntologyManager manager = null;
    static IRI ontologyIRI = null;
    static IRI documentIRI = null;
    static OWLOntology ontology = null;
    static OWLDataFactory factory = null;       
    static OWLReasoner hermit = null;       
    static HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> keywords = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, OWLException{

    manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    ontologyIRI = IRI.create("http://www.someurl.com/myOnto.owl");  
    documentIRI = IRI.create("file:/src/main/resources.xml");   
    SimpleIRIMapper mapper = new SimpleIRIMapper(ontologyIRI, documentIRI); 
    manager.addIRIMapper(mapper);   
    ontology = manager.createOntology(ontologyIRI); 
    factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();     

    OWLClass main = factory.getOWLClass(
            IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#main"));

    OWLClass clsA = factory.getOWLClass(
                IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#test"));

    OWLAxiom axiom = factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(clsA, main);
        AddAxiom addAxiom = new AddAxiom(ontology, axiom);

    manager.applyChange(addAxiom);

    //I insert some more classes and axioms here

    ReasonerFactory fac = new ReasonerFactory();
    hermit = fac.createReasoner(ontology);

    // Print the hierarchy, this works fine
    HirarchyPrinter hp = new HirarchyPrinter(manager, hermit);

    hp.printHierarchy(ontology, clazz);

    //now here I want to access the data, e.g. starting with this call:

    hermit.getSubClasses(main, false);
}
```

But I always get an Exception, ending always with the getTableau call

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.getTableau(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.isConsistent(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.throwInconsistentOntologyExceptionIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.checkPreConditions(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.getHierarchyNode(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.getSubClasses(Unknown Source)
at main.java.Main.main(Main.java:93)
```

I have no idea what causes this Exception and couldnt find any similar cases anywhere.

Greetings,
Daniel

Comment: Which version of HermiT are you using? I cannot replicate this with recent versions

Comment: I am using Hermit 1.3.8. Can this be caused by a messy SubClass Hirarchie? My classes are instantiated automatically, so maybe the fault is there.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what caused the error. I called the HirarchyPrinter before this call, and now after I outcommented that it works. Sry for not including that in the post...

Comment: If your class is manipulating the reasoner's internal state, then yes, that might be the cause.